# dynamic domain name setup

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

i want to create a dynamic subdomain

i have done this CNAME

```
*.domainname.com 14440 in <IP>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domains\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /site.php?url=%1&path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but it's gives me a cpanel home page
Great Success !
Apache is working on your cPanel® and WHM™ Server

can you help me where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Great Success" page is probably your default VirtualHost in apache.  If your dynamic subdomain (and your main domain) is all you are hosting, just make *that* your default host.  Otherwise, you will need to update settings for your VirtualHost accordingly:

> `<VirtualHost
>   example.com:80>
> ServerName:
>   example.com
> ServerAlias:
>   *.example.com
>  ...
>  </VirtualHost>`

That should hopefully fix the issue.
There is some additional info (for slightly more complicated virtualhost setups) at:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html
in case you decide to tweak it even further.